# vue js keep dropdown selected value even after page refresh

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs3

I have a dropdown, when user choose one value, it is push to the URL. Now if the user refresh the page the dropdown value should be selected by default if it is in URL. I am doing this in Laravel.
I tried as below, but when i refresh the page after choosing a dropdown value, the dropdown will be reset

```
<template>
<div class="mt-2">
           
            <select class="form-control" v-model="filter.size">
                <option value="">............</option>
                <option value="big">Big</option>
                <option value="small">Small</option>
            </select>
        </div>
<template>
<script>
    
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            
            filter: {
                size: this.$route.query.size,
     
            },
        };
    },

    mounted() {
  
    },

    watch: {
        filter: {
            handler() {
                this.$router.push({
                    query: this.filter,
                });
            },
            deep: true,
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

route

```
routes: [

    {
        path: '/home',
        component: App,
        name: App,
    
    },
],
```

view:registered here

```
   <div class="card-body">
         <search> </search>
   </div>
```

Comment: you'll want to use `sessionStorage`

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the variable value on the `mounted` hook

```
mounted() {
  this.filter.size = this.$route.query.size
},
```

Comment: It is recommanded to set the `filter` data directly as in vue2, nested value of object does not trigger reactivity:
`this.filter = {size: this.$route.query.size}`